# Вопрос по Flask, касаемо Button

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Начал изучать Python, а именно фреймфорк Flask.
Делаю приложение, которое должно принимать значение "город" и выводить погоду о нём.

**Вопрос:** Как сделать в нашем **index.html** поле ввода (куда мы будем вводить город) и привязанную к нему кнопку отправки, которая при нажатии будет возвращать наш ввод в функцию `декоратора` (я лично так себе представляю этот процесс), которая в свою очередь примет ввод и вернет результат?

**P.S.** Веб пока что не шарю.

Comment: А вы пошарьте, почитайте уроки про Flask, про формы, про процесс (который вы представляете неправильно)

Comment: Я с вами согласен. Если не сложно, посоветуйте, дайте источники

Answer (score 2):

```html
<form method="post" action="/weather">
    <input name="city">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
<form>
```

```py
from flask import request

# ...

@app.route('/weather', methods=['POST'])
def weather():
    city = request.form['city']  # введенный город
    return city  # отдаем ответ текстом
```

Для шаблонизации смотреть [тут](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/templates/).